# How to change Notification Icon in Maui Plugin.LocalNotification?

Tags: android, maui

I tried to set the Image but this code is not working.
The Icon is still plain white circle.

[image]

```
   var request = new NotificationRequest
   {
     NotificationId = notif.Id,
     Title = notif.Subject,
     Description = notif.Sender,
     Android = new Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidOptions
     {
     AutoCancel = true
     },
     Image = new NotificationImage
     {
         ResourceName = "AppIcon.png",
         FilePath = "\\Platforms\\Android\\Resources\\drawable\\"
    }
 };

  LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(request);
```

Comment: https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification/wiki/%5BAndroid%5D-How-to-change-notification-icon

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jason

Had to set it in platform specific in my case its android.
Add the image to Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable
rebuild and make sure it automatically add these lines.

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <MauiImage Include="Platforms\Android\Resources\drawable\noti_icon.png" />
</ItemGroup>

   var request = new NotificationRequest
{
    NotificationId = notif.Id,
    Title = notif.Subject,
    Description = notif.Sender,
    Android = new Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidOptions
    {
       AutoCancel = true,
       IconSmallName =
           {
              ResourceName = "noti_icon",
           }   
   }
};

LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(request);
```

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the code example. Just to add the `MauiImage` can be also `.svg`. And another thing, you can specify the Include path of `MauiImage` with wildcard like: `Platforms\Android\Resources\drawable\*`